# Differences of Component Diagrams and Deployment Diagrams?

Tags: uml

What are the  Differences of `Component Diagrams` and `Deployment Diagrams`?

Answer (score 10):

Simply put, a Component diagram shows you how different elements of your system have been grouped together (into assemblies / dlls etc) - and the link between these components. A Deployment diagram takes you one step further and describes on which hardware elements do these components reside.

So for example, if "Utility.dll" is a **component** and say it is **deployed** on the Client Machine (hardware). Then, the Component Diagram of this system will show Utility and its link with other components in the system (say.. Customer / SQL Packages). Whereas, the Deployment Diagram will show the hardware configuration - DB Server / Web Server / Client Machine .. and Utility component will be placed into the Client Machine Node.

Comment: This reply is in contrast to Andrew's answer, where he says "runtime modules" should be depicted in a deployment Diagram but you say Utility.dll would be a component in a component diagram.
Will you please elaborate?

Answer (score 7):

[Component Diagrams](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/componentDiagram.htm) are used to diagram the high level components which you will be developing. For example , in my application, i use COM to separate the modules. Each COM object runs in its own executable and is a modeled as a component.

[Deployment Diagrams](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/deploymentDiagram.htm) are used to diagram the actual runtime modules which are required to complete the system. This include your modules and any hardware / software which is required to complete your system. In my application, the Deployment diagram will contain the names of all the servers and which modules they will be running.

Comment: This reply is in contrast to Preet´s answer, where he says Utility.dll would be a component in a component diagram while you say "runtime modules" should be depicted in a deployment Diagram.
Will you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

A component diagram describes the organization of the physical components in a system.
Deployment diagrams depict the physical resources in a system including nodes, components, and connections.See for example here http://vinci.org/uml/